# In what ratio is the line joining the points $(1,3)$ and $(2,7)$ divided by the line $3x+y=9$?

Tags: analytic-geometry

> In what ratio the line, joining the points $(1,3)$ and $(2,7)$, divided by the line $3x+y=9$?

My Attempt:

Let the ratio be $m:n$. Then
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac {mx_2+nx_1}{m+n} , \frac {my_2+ny_1}{m+n}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac {m.2+n.1}{m+n}, \frac {m.7+n.3}{m+n}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac {2m+n}{m+n}, \frac {7m+3n}{m+n}\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, solve the line directly:

$$
\begin{cases}
y=4x -1 \\
y = 9 - 3x
\end{cases}$$

Thus we sovle for $x=\frac{10}{7}$. (The point is $(\frac{10}{7},\frac{33}{7})$, but you'll only need solve $x$ or solve $y$, no need for both.)

Notice that ratio wise, we could just focus on one of $x$ or $y$ axis, since it is a line (linear), focus on $x$-axis below:

$$\frac{m}{n}=\frac{\frac{10}{7}-1}{2-\frac{10}{7}}=\frac{3}{4}$$

**EDIT**

Segments over a line always have the same ratio for its projection onto axis or another line. For the following picture, we have

$$\frac{x_1}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{y_2}, \text{ and thus } \frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{y_1}{y_2}$$
[image]

Comment: I didn't understamd this one
" Notice that ratio wise, we could just focus on one of or axis, since it is a line (linear), focus on -axis below:"?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... So since it is a line, the ratio of the length of the two pieces equals the ratio of the projection to x-axis, or y-axis, or to any other line. And thus we do not need to actually calculate the length of the two pieces, but could just calculate the ratio of lengths projected onto the x-axis.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... I've edited the answer per your question in the comment

Answer (score 0):

HINT: your first equation has the form $$y=mx+n$$ with $$m=\frac{7-3}{2-1}=4$$  thus we have $$y=4x+n$$ plugging one Point in this eqaution we have
$$y=4x-1$$
can you compute the intersection Point with $$y=-3x+9$$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(1,3)$, $B(2,7)$ and $C$ be our point such that $AC:CB=m:n$.
Thus, $$C\left(\frac{n+2m}{m+n},\frac{3n+7m}{m+n}\right)$$ and 
$$3\cdot\frac{n+2m}{m+n}+\frac{3n+7m}{m+n}=9$$ or
$$4m=3n,$$
which gives $m:n=3:4$.

Answer (score 0):

The point diving the line segment $AB$, where $A=(1,3), B=(2,7)$, in the ratio $t:(1-t)$ is 
$$\big(2t+(1-t), \;7t+3(1-t)\big)=\big(t+1,\; 4t+3\big)$$
As this point also lies on the line $3x+y=9$, it must satisfy
$$3(t+1)+(4t+3)=9\\
\Longrightarrow t=\frac 37\quad \Longrightarrow t:(1-t)=\color{red}{3:4}$$.